# How to control dynamic class names which are auto-generated via CSS modules or styled-components with user-defined filters or other methods

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, user-defined-functions, reverse-engineering

Many websites today auto-generate dynamic class names via CSS modules or styled-components. This practice has the unfortunate and perhaps even deliberately malicious effect of disabling many user-defined filters and/or scripts; e.g. Reddit overrides all manner of client-side cosmetic changes; even simple things like karma are being forced upon the user due to the fact that there's apparently no persistent global identifier which the user could invoke to forbid the display of karma:

[An example screenshot of Reddit code illustrating the dynamic class names at hand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ux2VK.png)

I think this is authoritarian, inappropriate, and creates a horrible user experience. I don't believe it's reasonable that websites should exercise this kind of control. What exactly can the user do to reign in these seemingly un-manipulable dynamic class names? e.g., is there a way to reverse engineer the build processes used by CSS modules or styled-components in order to then inject the proper identifiers into a user-defined filter and/or script? Or are there better methods?

Note: I've already asked and received no decent response to this question on Webmaster, UX, and SuperUser. Is this the end of the road? Or is there a StackOverflow guru with a workable solution?

Comment: A workable solution... for what? You forgot to mention what it is you are trying to achieve.

Comment: How to control dynamic class names with user-defined filters or other methods? It's literally in the title of the post. I even provided a concrete example...

Comment: If you own the website we're talking about, simply disable whatever technology you're using that obfuscates the class names. If you don't own it, you really have no business controlling anything in that page. You are just a user, free to use it as any other user, as long as you do it within the boundaries of their EULA.

Comment: It's unclear how obfuscating class names can be inappropriate and what's the connection between class naming conventions and user experience. However, there is one thing that ***is*** quite clear: your question is off-topic here. Please read [ask].

Comment: You're essentially espousing the right to private tyranny. It's arguable whether or not the user is subject to any EULA, which in most cases they never consented to in the first place. Many think users have the right or power to circumvent these schemes.

Comment: I disagree that the question is off-topic. I think that's your subjective opinion.

Comment: It would be, if it were an opinion. But it's [a fact](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). However, I'm am here to help, provided you know how to ask. My subjective opinion is that, if you put enough effort into providing users of this community with a decent technical challenge, other than *"control dynamic class names on a website I do not own"* some of them, including myself, might be able to provide a technical solution. Could you please transform your question from a general rant into a specific technical programming challenge?

Comment: So far it looks like you believe that by solving problem X (controlling class names on a website you don't own) you'll solve problem Y (which you haven't specified yet and seems to be your ability to view that website in a different way that it was designed and provided). Please describe problem Y, which is likely much easier to solve than problem X. Also specify what technology you want to use and, most importantly, provide us with the results of your research and at least one coding attempt for the task at hand. Without them, your question is off-topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To hide karma spans on a comments page on Reddit, today, you could run the following JavaScript:

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('span')).filter(i => /(\d+)\spoint/.test(i.innerHTML)).forEach(i => i.style.display = 'none');
```

Tested it [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/ProgrammerHumor/comments/9qy9yr/programming_is_like_magic/).
However, it only hides karma on the rendered comments, not on the ones that are not yet loaded.

To programatically open all "moreComments" links on a page, you'd need to run:

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('div')).filter(i => /moreComments-/.test(i.id)).forEach(i => i.querySelector('p').click())
```

Depending on how many hidden comments are on the page, you'd need to wait a while until all requests resolve and all comments are rendered.

At which point running the first line will hide all karma spans on the page.

---

And this might not work tomorrow, as Reddit own that code and have the right, the ability and the resources to change its inner structure, layout or design as they see fit, any number of times a day, so that any puny attempts of altering the rendered output of their service, by coder wannabes like me and you, remain futile.

---

**Edit:** Ever since I answered your question I wanted to provide some helpful insight on how to approach StackOverflow. I hope you [find it](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/txyLnavf/embedded/result/#Result) helpful or, at least, entertaining.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you build an array containing all divs; then filter the result to create an integer list of every `moreComments` function; then `forEach` instance of `moreComments` you click `p` to expand the results. After the page loads fully, you build another array, this time containing all `spans`, to then filter the results to create an integer list of `point` strings; then, `forEach` instance of `point` you essentially nullify the display of the preceding characters. I know I'm not describing this precisely, but that seems to be roughly what this script does. Nice work.

Comment: The following code is working well:

`Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('div')).filter(i => /moreComments-/.test(i.id)).forEach(i => i.querySelector('p').click());`

`setTimeout(function() {
    Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('span')).filter(i => /(\d+)\spoint/.test(i.innerHTML)).forEach(i => i.style.display = 'none');
},7000)`

Not sure how to start this script for embedded pages loaded from the main page, however.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by *"embedded pages loaded from the main page"*, because you still have not provided any technical details of what you're trying to do. I'm assuming it's because it's something you think ethers might consider wrong. If you're embedding content from Reddit there's no way you can run js on their page without them allowing it from your specific domain. The only 2 ways to go are: using an API (if they provide one) or scraping. In both cases you have control over the end result.

Comment: @intro, see addition to my answer. Happy coding!

Comment: The embedded pages are native to Reddit. They open when you click on links from the subreddit's main page. And yes, I've read over your other remark and you make some fair points. I didn't understand the question sufficiently to know the proper level of generality with which to frame the challenge, which seemed more pervasive than the particular case of Reddit karma. I did, however, make time to research the problem at some length, which is why I knew some of the underlying terminology. Of course, as a non-coder in most respects, it's difficult for me to spell out the implementation details.

Comment: In that case your only way to run JS in those pages is from a browser extension, like [tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en), right?

Comment: Didn't mean to get into a discussion about this, it's not that important. I'm just noting that the script doesn't get injected into the embedded pages for some reason. That includes when I use extensions like tampermonkey, by the way. Again, hard to parse this issue. I'll open a new question later.